# TLS handshake fails between a Java 1.8 client and a Java 1.7 TLS 1.1 server running in FIPS mode, even after disabling TLS 1.2 in the client side

Tags: security, ssl, java-8, fips, nss

The SSL / TLS handshake between a "Java 1.7 TLS 1.1 server" and a "Java 1.8 client" fails in my environment with the following exception on the server side:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm:
>   SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips

Following are the details of the server and the client in my environment:

**Server:**

- The server uses Java 1.7u45 and is running in FIPS 140 compliant mode
  as mentioned in
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html.
- The server uses Mozilla Network Security Services (NSS) version
  3.14.3 as the cryptographic provider.
- The server is running on SLES 11 SP3 (SuSE Linux Enterprise Server)
  operating system and uses the following NSS RPMS provided by the OS:

  - mozilla-nss-3.14.3-0.11.11
  - mozilla-nss-tools-3.14.3-0.11.11
  - mozilla-nspr-4.9.6-0.3.1
  - libfreebl3-3.14.3-0.11.11
  - libsoftokn3-3.14.3-0.11.11
- An important point to note is that NSS version 3.14.3 DOES NOT
  support TLS 1.2.
- The server uses Java 1.7u45 because of the Java bug "8028192 Use of
  PKCS11-NSS provider  in FIPS mode broken" introduced in Java 1.7u51.
  See "Known Issues" section "Area: security-libs/javax.net.ssl" in
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html
  for more details.

**Client:**

- The client is a Java Swing based client application which is launched
  using Java Web Start.
- The client uses Java 1.8u25 and is running on Windows 7 Professional SP1 operating system.
- Since the server does not support TLS 1.2, TLS 1.2 has been disabled in the client side in the "Advanced" tab of the Java Control
  Panel as mentioned in
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/jcp.html#A1153011.

**Question:**

- Since the server does not support TLS 1.2, I disabled TLS 1.2 on the client side.
- I could not figure out why the handshake fails "even after" disabling TLS 1.2 on the client side. Can you please help me with this?

**Additional observations:**

- The same scenario works fine if Java 1.7 (any version) is used and TLS 1.2 is disabled on the client side.
- The same exception "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips" is thrown in the server side if Java 1.7 (any version) is used and TLS 1.2 is enabled in the client side.
- It fails if Java 1.8 (any version) is used in the client side, even after disabling TLS 1.2.

**Server side SSL debug logs:**

- It seems that the handshake is first initiated with TLS 1.1 using the cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA.
- After this, for some reason, the handshake is re-initiated with TLS 1.2 using the cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 which fails with the exception "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips".

> TLS 1.1 Java 1.7u45 server + Java 1.8u25 TLS 1.2 disabled client -
>   fails:

```
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ClientHello, TLSv1.1
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | RandomCookie:  GMT: 1417167224 bytes = { 55, 212, 126, 68, 49, 1, 205, 58, 112, 15, 1, 9, 38, 31, 58, 188, 229, 115, 10, 61, 249, 209, 98, 140, 149, 113, 149, 231 }
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Session ID:  {84, 120, 65, 114, 3, 180, 96, 53, 232, 47, 28, 70, 58, 150, 117, 9, 169, 7, 94, 233, 94, 198, 136, 202, 240, 130, 18, 23, 89, 10, 220, 111}
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Compression Methods:  { 0 }
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | %% Resuming [Session-135, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ServerHello, TLSv1.1
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | RandomCookie:  GMT: 1417167218 bytes = { 175, 0, 103, 107, 78, 20, 172, 204, 4, 196, 148, 153, 126, 87, 188, 255, 85, 219, 140, 39, 41, 136, 51, 33, 169, 31, 36, 150 }
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Session ID:  {84, 120, 65, 114, 3, 180, 96, 53, 232, 47, 28, 70, 58, 150, 117, 9, 169, 7, 94, 233, 94, 198, 136, 202, 240, 130, 18, 23, 89, 10, 220, 111}
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Compression Method: 0
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher suite:  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | CONNECTION KEYGEN:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Client Nonce:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0000: 54 78 41 78 37 D4 7E 44   31 01 CD 3A 70 0F 01 09  TxAx7..D1..:p...
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0010: 26 1F 3A BC E5 73 0A 3D   F9 D1 62 8C 95 71 95 E7  &.:..s.=..b..q..
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Server Nonce:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0000: 54 78 41 72 AF 00 67 6B   4E 14 AC CC 04 C4 94 99  TxAr..gkN.......
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0010: 7E 57 BC FF 55 DB 8C 27   29 88 33 21 A9 1F 24 96  .W..U..').3!..$.
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Master Secret:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Client MAC write Secret:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Server MAC write Secret:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Client write key:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Server write key:
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ... no IV derived for this protocol
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-300, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 81
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-300, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** Finished
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | verify_data:  { 205, 73, 239, 162, 189, 111, 93, 112, 252, 191, 178, 72 }
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-300, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 64
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-299, READ: TLSv1.1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-299, READ: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 64
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** Finished
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | verify_data:  { 19, 183, 83, 202, 63, 74, 163, 0, 247, 151, 206, 20 }
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-299 - /AuthServices/auth/tokens, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 184
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-299 - /AuthServices/auth/tokens, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 2987
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | qtp1981883520-299, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 5
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Allow legacy hello messages: true
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Is initial handshake: true
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Is secure renegotiation: false
2014/11/28 15:03:38 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Is secure renegotiation: false
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | RandomCookie:  GMT: 1417167229 bytes = { 209, 207, 128, 77, 244, 126, 201, 133, 122, 149, 46, 174, 146, 131, 232, 171, 236, 114, 188, 239, 89, 136, 179, 55, 42, 35, 10, 208 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Session ID:  {}
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Session ID:  {}
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Compression Methods:  { 0 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Compression Methods:  { 0 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | %% Initialized:  [Session-136, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | %% Initialized:  [Session-136, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | %% Negotiating:  [Session-136, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | RandomCookie:  GMT: 1417167223 bytes = { 117, 144, 129, 63, 132, 34, 26, 83, 118, 25, 122, 135, 116, 24, 242, 213, 196, 31, 25, 127, 155, 153, 6, 132, 244, 45, 21, 235 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | RandomCookie:  GMT: 1417167223 bytes = { 117, 144, 129, 63, 132, 34, 26, 83, 118, 25, 122, 135, 116, 24, 242, 213, 196, 31, 25, 127, 155, 153, 6, 132, 244, 45, 21, 235 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Session ID:  {84, 120, 65, 119, 78, 220, 0, 216, 29, 255, 202, 86, 198, 210, 97, 121, 235, 184, 87, 232, 34, 43, 85, 29, 148, 43, 201, 241, 189, 70, 130, 185}
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Compression Method: 0
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** Certificate chain
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | chain [0] = [
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | [
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Version: V3
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Subject: CN=dev-05.labs.blr.com, O=webserver
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Key:  SunPKCS11-NSSfips RSA public key, 2048 bits (id 1, session object)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Key:  SunPKCS11-NSSfips RSA public key, 2048 bits (id 1, session object)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   modulus: 19751124565775544542661601941034719218747286997557229376272410409764009924174952830102822006739940996361158891315994655677031683410457285645708620145915789088144941408425439122384306771006790672852952487887077643219829713631271285091822690455402307000211724434432943370113476924425722411995320247744734057517566666508974254720742261526685687656494544221796453195966155694205640019924093341684193258103280171653517687458035087335731929833587535142452049552301009807817546366586239918288540321429443922231821575519420587811789981092934767950075857907111279056051594689275813767976468618202672668356345198890748632149983
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   public exponent: 65537
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   public exponent: 65537
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Validity: [From: Tue Nov 25 14:37:52 IST 2014,
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |                To: Thu Nov 01 14:37:52 IST 2114]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Issuer: CN=dev-05.labs.blr.com, O=webserver
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   SerialNumber: [    0d54f951]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Certificate Extensions: 1
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | [1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | SubjectKeyIdentifier [
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | KeyIdentifier [
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0000: 94 2D EB EF E8 04 5F 84   B2 BA F6 A5 C9 58 D3 79  .-...._......X.y
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0010: 44 8F 40 07                                        D.@.
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   Signature:
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0000: 39 59 42 B8 26 F6 64 7E   CA C1 33 7C 60 6A FC 80  9YB.&.d...3.`j..
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0010: 5F AF 51 89 98 B7 AC 0C   27 DA A1 60 AD 5B 87 11  _.Q.....'..`.[..
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0020: D8 95 E3 37 D2 CB E3 8A   6F CF 82 F3 4C AA B6 42  ...7....o...L..B
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0030: F5 8B 67 0B D9 F2 3E FA   FE 81 C5 77 78 47 E2 61  ..g...>....wxG.a
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0040: 33 DC 97 CB FC 04 1D 99   18 84 C3 DC 28 8D 14 D7  3...........(...
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0050: AF 71 1C E6 41 FC D1 71   CB C3 50 66 5E 28 AF EB  .q..A..q..Pf^(..
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0060: AF 80 52 CC 89 BE 0D 0B   58 1C CA 1C 34 36 BA 96  ..R.....X...46..
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0070: F2 FE 18 73 6B F7 09 35   94 AC 8E CB F2 83 47 62  ...sk..5......Gb
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0080: 20 FD 64 64 72 D6 89 D7   77 A7 D0 17 43 7E FF 44   .ddr...w...C..D
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 0090: 57 B5 1D 27 24 1D F5 87   86 E9 29 EF DE E7 D2 2E  W..'$.....).....
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00A0: 32 EE 3D 82 7C 53 7E 93   E9 5F 5E 9C 62 F5 31 C7  2.=..S..._^.b.1.
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00B0: 9E 54 58 50 01 EE 58 18   81 6D 52 C0 EB CA CA 52  .TXP..X..mR....R
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00C0: 26 CC 3C 9D E5 60 BE BE   A1 E6 D5 79 66 F9 0C FD  &.<..`.....yf...
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00D0: BB 9E 36 E5 31 FC D4 68   8A 06 8D A0 0B 68 BA 2B  ..6.1..h.....h.+
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00E0: 1E AF 51 4A 6C BC 2D 7D   B4 04 EA D6 DA 28 9B 64  ..QJl.-......(.d
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | 00F0: F9 FF 35 7B E7 91 02 01   37 E7 C2 AA 8D 1E 48 22  ..5.....7.....H"
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ***
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Server key: SunPKCS11-NSSfips EC public key, 256 bits (id 1668, session object)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   public x coord: 22811020849167726801730368600918463139597169803826118722525163464343792847845
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   public y coord: 73886304187565809239631250457098470068449769526968865962213829575389354072377
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |   parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ServerHelloDone
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1237
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 70
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | *** ECDHClientKeyExchange
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | ECDH Public value:  { 4, 121, 116, 89, 85, 251, 91, 15, 91, 227, 244, 77, 243, 1, 197, 145, 33, 117, 182, 143, 76, 42, 19, 121, 131, 88, 88, 58, 225, 42, 50, 178, 100, 17, 18, 128, 220, 237, 192, 247, 67, 173, 13, 185, 114, 213, 250, 172, 58, 145, 158, 237, 115, 94, 129, 246, 254, 151, 126, 190, 182, 240, 45, 57, 62 }
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | SESSION KEYGEN:
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | PreMaster Secret:
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | (key bytes not available)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, handling exception: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | %% Invalidated:  [Session-136, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, called closeSocket()
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Fri Nov 28 15:03:43 IST 2014|WARNING|Thread-601|ccs.comp.clientproxy.ProxiedClientListener$ProxyConnection.run
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       Error processing requests from proxied client : unestablished
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips (java.security.ProviderException); Root cause: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1476)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:92)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:69)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at ccs.comp.clientproxy.ProxiedClientListener$ProxyConnection.getNext(ProxiedClientListener.java:438)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at ccs.comp.clientproxy.ProxiedClientListener$ProxyConnection.run(ProxiedClientListener.java:245)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1842)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSession(SSLSocketImpl.java:2171)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at ccs.comp.clientproxy.ProxiedClientListener.listen(ProxiedClientListener.java:126)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at ccs.comp.clientproxy.ProxiedClientListener.run(ProxiedClientListener.java:105)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:1060)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys(Handshaker.java:999)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:234)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               ... 3 more
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |       Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SunTls12MasterSecret for provider SunPKCS11-NSSfips
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:100)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:109)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:287)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(JsseJce.java:269)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:1052)
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    |               ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the server does not support TLS 1.2, I disabled TLS 1.2 on the client side.
>
> I could not figure out why the handshake fails "even after" disabling TLS 1.2 on the client side. Can you please help me with this?

And:

```
...
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
2014/11/28 15:03:43 | INFO   | jvm 1    | Thread-31, called closeSocket()
```

Just guessing, the the PRF (pseudorandom function) in TLS 1.1 and earlier use MD5 (and SHA1). The TLS 1.2 PRF uses SHA2 family (IIRC). The library is probably being over-zealous with respect to MD5.

Its kind of like trying to get half-pregnant. How do you allow MD5 internally for one function, but not allow it on other functions and still pass a validation with a testing lab?

So you should try to work with the libraries and enable TLS 1.2.

---

> The client is a Java Swing based client application which is launched using Java Web Start.

I think the first step you should perform is drop the Java client that can't cope with TLS 1.2, and verify the server works as expected. That will give you a baseline of sorts.

You can use the following OpenSSL command to test the server with TLS 1.2 enabled:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect www.example.com:443 -servername www.example.com
```

You can also specify a specific cipher by using the `-cipher` option. For example, `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` is [`AES128-SHA`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) in OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect www.example.com:443 -servername www.example.com -cipher AES128-SHA
```

You can even fecth a page with something like (notice the addition of `-ign_eof`):

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.example.com\r\n\r\n" |  openssl s_client -ign_eof -tls1_2 -connect...
```

---

Java is pretty lame when it comes to TLS protocols and cipher suites prior to Java 8. Though available, TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are ***not*** enabled by default in Java 7 and earlier. You need to explicitly enable them.

In addition, Java sneaks in SSLv3 even when you don't ask for it. To see for yourself, try `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")` and see if SSLv3 is an enabled protocol :)

You can see an example of enabling available protocols and cipher suites at [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1037590/608639)

---

Interestingly, use of MD5 as a PRF in TLS is allowed by NIST. But its a very specific exception. Its allowed because the PRF does not require the property of collision resistance - it just needs to extract entropy.

The following is from NIST's [SP 800-135](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-135-rev1/sp800-135-rev1.pdf):

> The outputs from both P_MD5 and P_SHA-1 are XOR ed together to produce
> the PRF output. This PRF is used as both a randomness extraction step
> to generate the master secret and as a key expansion step to derive
> keying material for the protocol from the master secret.
>
> The TLS 1.0 and 1.1 KDF is approved when the following conditions are
> satisfied:
> (1) The TLS 1.0 and 1.1 KDF is performed in the context of
> the TLS protocol.
> (2) SHA-1 and HMAC are as specified in FIPSs 180-3
> and 198-1, respectively.

Comment: (1) Java7 disables 1.1 and 1.2 *in client* by default, but at least they are available. Before 7 they aren't even implemented. 
(2) MD5 is FIPS-approved only in limited cases like TLS1.0/1.1 KDF. But the OP's log clearly shows it is trying the TLS1.2 KDF, 
which is SHA-2, and FAILS because NSS (NOT SunJCE) doesn't support 1.2 -- as he said at the top.