# SSL with self-signed certificate

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, certificate

When I'm trying to connect to URL with self-signed certificate, Java doesn't allow me to do that. In my situation I can't use custom SSL socket factory without certificate check, so I need to use PKS12 certificate and add it in the trusted store.
My questions is - what are my actions to get PKS12 certificate? I exported certificate from URL via browser tools (it's X.509), then what should I do?

Comment: See the Javadoc for the `keytool`. It's all described there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

Taken from:

[How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java HttpsURLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) URL.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLFACTORY);
connection.setMethod("POST");

KeyStore KEY_STORE = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(TRUST_STORE, PASSWORD);
TRUST_STORE.close();

TrustManagerFactory managerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
managerFactory.init(KEY_STORE);
SSLSocketFactoryEx SSLFACTORY = new SSLSocketFactoryEx();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(factory);
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
```

Taken From:

[Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037590/which-cipher-suites-to-enable-for-ssl-socket/23365536#23365536)

Thanks @jww

```
class SSLSocketFactoryEx extends SSLSocketFactory
{
    public SSLSocketFactoryEx() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(null,null,null);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(km, tm, random);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(ctx);
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getDefaultProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        m_ctx.init(km, tm, random);

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = ctx;

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    protected String[] GetProtocolList()
    {
        String[] preferredProtocols = { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3" };
        String[] availableProtocols = null;

        SSLSocket socket = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();

            availableProtocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
            Arrays.sort(availableProtocols);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[]{ "TLSv1" };
        }
        finally
        {
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredProtocols.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableProtocols, preferredProtocols[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredProtocols[i]);
        }

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    protected String[] GetCipherList()
    {
        String[] preferredCiphers = {

            // *_CHACHA20_POLY1305 are 3x to 4x faster than existing cipher suites.
            //   http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html
            // Use them if available. Normative names can be found at (TLS spec depends on IPSec spec):
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nir-ipsecme-chacha20-poly1305-01
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mavrogiannopoulos-chacha-tls-02
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            // Done with bleeding edge, back to TLS v1.2 and below
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",

            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",

            // TLS v1.0 (with some SSLv3 interop)
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",

            // RSA key transport sucks, but they are needed as a fallback.
            // For example, microsoft.com fails under all versions of TLS
            // if they are not included. If only TLS 1.0 is available at
            // the client, then google.com will fail too. TLS v1.3 is
            // trying to deprecate them, so it will be interesteng to see
            // what happens.
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
        };

        String[] availableCiphers = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            availableCiphers = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            Arrays.sort(availableCiphers);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[] {
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
            };
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredCiphers.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableCiphers, preferredCiphers[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredCiphers[i]);
        }

        aa.add("TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV");

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    private SSLContext m_ctx;

    private String[] m_ciphers;
    private String[] m_protocols;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this: `SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");`. It returns both `SSL` and `TLS` protocols; and not just `TLS` like one would expect. See, for example, [SSLSocketFactoryEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536) to force TLS (and remove SSL).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a tool called [InstallCert](https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java).  It will download the self-signed certificate and import it to a new truststore/keystore.