# Will SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") supports TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 also?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, openssl, poodle-attack

In my java Code i am creating one instance of SSL Context using command

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

But in my tomcat server i am setting TLSv1.2 and i am getting handshake error.

How we can support all the TLS protocols using this method like in cpp we have SSLV23 client method which will support all protocols.

Comment: Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); suports all protocols :)

Comment: *`SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");`* - it gets worse. On Java 8 and below, you also get SSLv3. A bug report was filed with Oracle, but it was closed as "won't fix" because its by design. Also see [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/608639)

Comment: do you've the bug id?

Comment: @mahan07 `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")` does not necessarily support all protocols - it depends of JVM. In my case the class configured like this cannot connect to an Apache server using TLSv1 being run on IBM JVM 1.7.0 when it **can** connect being run on Oracle JVM 1.7.0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To use TLSv1.2 try to use below code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
```

Comment: May I know how to apply this `sslContext` into my `RestTemplate`? I am working in Spring version 3.0.x, keep trying but cant get it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836065/i-o-error-on-post-request-for-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset/55333280#55333280