# I/O error on POST request for... java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring `Rest Template` to call a REST service that is hosted at an SSL endpoint. After the first request, I am getting the below error. The environment is AWS EC2, `Open JDK 1.8.161`, `Linux`. The endpoint only supports `TLSv1.2` and `1.3`.

```
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://mycompany.com": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    ... more stack here
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at .....
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated=!!

Comment: Is this the whole stack trace?

Comment: Please also post your java code.

Comment: Is Connection: Keep-Alive? You can check this from response header.  If yes what are the Keep-Alive parameters? Ex:  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=20

Comment: That was my first thought. I had the same issue on here and now deploying the changes with a keep alive and a connection pool to try to fix the issue. My environment is fully TLS1.2 and over AWS ec2

Comment: Please show us your `RestTemplate` configuration? Do you have anything configured for SSL?

Comment: It was the default configuration for RestTemplate from the builder.

Answer (score 20):

This quite feels like the protocol issue. The AWS is fully TLS 1.2 or higher supporting, but the client is not. The `Rest Template` if not configured otherwise, will start negotiation with `TLS 1.0`. You have to forcefully make the client to connect only with 1.2 or 1.3 protocol stacks.

In general, this can be configured while creating the client. Something similar to this

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null, null, null);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(context)
    .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

You can find how to tune the template based on the spring version. Forcing the client to negotiate only on the allowed protocols will solve this problem.

Comment: Total sense, I actually resolved the issue last week. I moved the http client to our software default (OkHttp) and specified that the TLS version should always be 1.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used that properties -

`"-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"`,

The problem solved when that property is removed from command line.

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -jar app.jar

java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Essentially, this JVM arg should be set to true