# SocketException Connection Reset error on resttemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring, networking, resttemplate

I started to get ConnectionReset error when i try make request to an apple api url.

I made no code change but it suddenly started to give errors. When i call the url with curl command i can get answer but when i call it from the code it throws the below exception.

What might be causing this error?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api-applecareconnect.apple.com/enroll-service/1.0/show-order-details": Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:534)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:430)


Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:82)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:519)
    ... 122 more
```

Comment: looks like from https. Can you try to change your http request from `https` to `http`?

Comment: But it is working fine with curl request and it was working fine within the code too.

Comment: As you said, you don't make any change. Just thought, maybe you have typo by mixed `http` with `https`. If you use `https` from the begining, ignore me.

Comment: Is it throwing the exception randomly? A connection reset is originated on the remote server or a firewall in the middle so it's not easy to determine the cause. Check your app is sending the correct packets and that you are not using a deprecated protocol or SSL suite.

Comment: No not randomly, it throws everytime.

Comment: Are your application behind some kind of firewall or proxy?

Comment: Couple of possibilities to eliminate ... could the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` in the stack be reusing a connection where it wasn't before?  It might be worth switching to a `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager` to eliminate this.  Also, 'Connection reset' can sometimes be as basic as not connecting to where you think you are, e.g. due to a hosts file entry (or other DNS change).  If curl is working fine from the same machine though this probably isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was a firewall policy changed without our information. It blocked the access to apple servers.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here [I/O error on POST request for... java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836065/i-o-error-on-post-request-for-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset/55333280#55333280)

This seems to be the same problem. @EspringDev is actually pointing the right direction.
As per apple , they support all the versions through 1.0 to 1.3. But the API you consume could have a [SSL/TLS security policy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411526-tlsminimumsupportedprotocol?language=java) . I hope this will solve the issue.