# Add TLSv1.2 support at runtime for Android 4.0

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

One of my company's APIs is being updated to use TLSv1.1 or higher. Unfortunately, Android 4.0 does not natively support those protocols.

I think it's possible; navigating to https://www.howsmyssl.com using Chrome on a 4.0 device shows that it's using TLSv1.2. I have seen some suggestions using SSLSocket ([particularly this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/2608235)), but they have not worked within my app. I also tried using [ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.html#installIfNeeded(android.content.Context)) to add TLSv1.2 via Google Play Services; according to howsmyssl, the device was still using TLSv1.0.

Is there a way to add support for TLSv1.2 at runtime for Android 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

Android itself did not add TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 support until Android 4.1/`android-16` so you'll have to use a library that does not rely on Android's `SSLSocket` in order to get newer than TLSv1.0 on older Android releases.  You can see what is officially supported by looking at the reference for [SSLSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).

The [NetCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher) library will provide `HttpsURLConnection` instances that are configured with the best possible TLS settings for that Android version, but that still won't give you TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 on older than Android 4.1.