# How to add SSL cipher suites to HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

I have exceptions while login into a https web site using `HttpsURLConnection` after updating to `Android 5.0 lollipop`. (It worked well in android 4.4 kitkat)

```
05-08 02:18:12.277  32344-32482/com.soonoo.mobilecampus E/INFO﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
```

I've read the article about android 5.0's changes. (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#ssl)

It seems that I should add some cipher suites required by a server.

Can anyone please give me some advice/code about how to add cipher suites to `HttpsURLConnection`? I tried below answer but didn't work for me...
([Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037590/which-cipher-suites-to-enable-for-ssl-socket#answer-23365536))

I used below code to connect:

```
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(Sites.LOGIN_URL).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(loginQuery.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(loginQuery);
        output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add cipher suites to a client. I suggest using an online tool like [Qualys SSL Labs' SSL Server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to check what cipher suites are supported by the server. If the server does not support any cipher suite that [Android 5 supports](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=5.0.0), I'm afraid there isn't much you can do from a client side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There exists only one cipher suite that `android 5.0` and `server` support. (`TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5`)  Same exception, however still occurs. Do you know why?