# Java does not accept 2 methods with same name

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I need to run the code shown below (obtained from:[Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037590/which-cipher-suites-to-enable-for-ssl-socket/23365536#23365536)).

The problem is that the code contains several methods named: createSocket with different argument types. The eclipse shows me error saying:
[image]

I read that Java can have multiple methods with same name as long as the arguments are different (method overloading). I do not know why this is causing me a problem here?

The code is:

```
class SSLSocketFactoryEx extends SSLSocketFactory
{
    public SSLSocketFactoryEx() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(null,null,null);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(km, tm, random);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(ctx);
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getDefaultProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        m_ctx.init(km, tm, random);

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = ctx;

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    protected String[] GetProtocolList()
    {
        String[] preferredProtocols = { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3" };
        String[] availableProtocols = null;

        SSLSocket socket = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();

            availableProtocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
            Arrays.sort(availableProtocols);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[]{ "TLSv1" };
        }
        finally
        {
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredProtocols.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableProtocols, preferredProtocols[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredProtocols[i]);
        }

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    protected String[] GetCipherList()
    {
        String[] preferredCiphers = {

            // *_CHACHA20_POLY1305 are 3x to 4x faster than existing cipher suites.
            //   http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html
            // Use them if available. Normative names can be found at (TLS spec depends on IPSec spec):
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nir-ipsecme-chacha20-poly1305-01
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mavrogiannopoulos-chacha-tls-02
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            // Done with bleeding edge, back to TLS v1.2 and below
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",

            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",

            // TLS v1.0 (with some SSLv3 interop)
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",

            // RSA key transport sucks, but they are needed as a fallback.
            // For example, microsoft.com fails under all versions of TLS
            // if they are not included. If only TLS 1.0 is available at
            // the client, then google.com will fail too. TLS v1.3 is
            // trying to deprecate them, so it will be interesteng to see
            // what happens.
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
        };

        String[] availableCiphers = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            availableCiphers = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            Arrays.sort(availableCiphers);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[] {
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
            };
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredCiphers.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableCiphers, preferredCiphers[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredCiphers[i]);
        }

        aa.add("TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV");

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    private SSLContext m_ctx;

    private String[] m_ciphers;
    private String[] m_protocols;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to use @override before the concerned method:

```
@Override
    public Socket  createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }
```

Nothing has changed, the problem still exists.

Also, please, note that at the end of the code, there is this part:

```
@Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

The error has disappeared when I commented that method. 
The SSLFactory is built in class. How can I rerach it to check its code?

Comment: I think same method exist in `SSLSocketFactory` use `@Override` annotation on it. Or show us code of `SSLSocketFactory`

Comment: Normally eclipse will mark 2 or more duplicate methods if there are duplicates. If it is marking only 1 method as duplicate, then do a clean and build, that should mostly solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that `createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)` already exists in the super class you are extending (`SSLSocketFactory`).

When extending a class in Java the methods in that super class become methods in the subclass (unless a method's [scope does not allow it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)). Therefore when you add the `createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)` method to your subclass eclipse thinks that you are trying to define a new method with the same signature as the super class' method. Try adding an `@Override` annotation above your version of the method.

Or since the super class already implements that method, you can remove your implementation and still be able to call the `createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)` through your `SSLSocketFactoryEx` class.

**Edit:** Given the information you provided I need to revise this answer. For you it isn't just that you were trying to Override a super method, but rather that the super method was already Overridden in your class. If you need to keep your method's functionality (i.e the `SSLSocketFactory` implementation of `createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)` is not sufficient for your needs) you must delete the other Overridden method. Overriding only works once per sub-class so you can't Override the same method twice. So just delete one of the Overridden methods and insert your code into the other so that you only have one implementation in your class.

Keep in mind that Java *does* allow methods of the same name with different parameters. ***But*** just renaming the parameters doesn't count as different parameters. Both of those methods in your class have the same signature of `createSocket(Socket, String, int, boolean)` regardless of the parameter names.

Comment: could you plz check my edit and give me your advise.

Comment: @user2192774 I updated my answer to reflect your updated question.