# Enable TLSv1.2 and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Cipher Suite

Tags: ssl, encryption, java-7, tls1.2, java-security

```
Server: 
TLS Version: v1.2
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 

Client:
JRE 1.7
```

I am receiving the below error when I try to connect to the Server from Client through SSL directly:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
```

The below code enables TLSv1.2

```
  Set<String> enabledTLSSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(sslsocket.getEnabledProtocols()));
  enabledTLSSet.add("TLSv1.2");      
  sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols(enabledTLSSet.toArray(new String[enabledTLSSet.size()]));
```

The below code enables TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Cipher Suite:

```
Set<String> enabledCipherSuitesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(sslsocket.getEnabledCipherSuites()));
      enabledCipherSuitesSet.add("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
      sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuitesSet.toArray(new String[enabledCipherSuitesSet.size()]));
```

After doing both of the above from Java code, I'm able to connect to the server successfully through SSL.

Is it possible to enable/force `TLSv1.2` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` in Java 7 without changing any Java Code through properties, parameters or Debug props?

I tried all of the below properties in all forms and combinations (enabling and disabling) and failed.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true
```

I'm executing the program similar to the below:

```
java -jar -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake SSLPoker.jar <SERVER> 443
```

SSLPoker contains the below code:

```
package com.ashok.ssl;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and prints the response - Ashok Goli. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 */
public class SSLPoke {

  /**
   * The main method.
   * Usage: $java -jar SSLPoker.jar <host> <port>
   *
   * @param args the arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.println("Usage: " + SSLPoke.class.getName() + " <host> <port>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
      SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
      SSLSocket sslsocket =
          (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

      InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

      // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
      out.write(1);

      while (in.available() > 0) {
        System.out.print(in.read());
      }
      System.out.println("Successfully connected");

    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers how to achieve this with no Java code changes would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't add TLS cipher suites without adding a whole security provider, such as Bouncy Castle, which indeed may support that one.

Comment: What are the settings that I need to play around with to achieve this?

Comment: I did add TLS and successfully connected to the Server with the code above. Just looking for a way to do that via configuration.

Comment: Ashok + @EJP: you don't need Bouncy, and anyway there is no JCA/provider interface for individual SSL/TLS suites, only the whole protocol. Java7 JSSE supports that suite out of the box. In fact it is already enabled by default so you don't need to enable it, and TLSv1.2 is already enabled by default for *server* side so you don't need to enable it. But all suites that use a 256-bit data cipher will only be *used* if the **unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files** (2 jars in JRE/lib/security) are installed; are they?

Comment: For your client, the `https.*` properties only apply to connections made by `HttpsURLConnection`, i.e., connections from `URLConnection` with a URL whose scheme is `https:`. "Just-SSL/TLS" connections with `SSLSocketFactory` do not use them. For those you must call the `.setEnabled*` methods on the socket after creating it and before doing any input, output, or (explicit) `.startHandshake()`.

Comment: Youare absolutely right. And I did just what you said above. The snippets in the question show that. Is there a way to do it without changing Code?

Comment: Related, see [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1037590/608639)

Answer (score 19):

It is only possible if you use a simple HTTPS connection (not SSL Sockets) using the properties

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

See the post at http://fsanglier.blogspot.com.es/

> Java 7 introduced support for TLS v1.2 (refer to
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html)
>   BUT does not enable it by default. In other words, your client app
>   must explicitly specify "TLS v1.2" at SSLContext creation, or
>   otherwise will just not be able to use it.

If you need to use directly secure socket protocol, create a "TLSv1.2" SSLContext at application startup and use the SSLContext.setDefault(ctx) call to register that new context as the default one.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
```

Comment: Wow... This is indeed required. I noticed they were ignored, but did not expect the server to already require TLS 1.2

Answer (score 8):

The JREs disable all 256-bit crypto by default. To enable you can download **Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files** here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Replace the **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar** jars files into your lib/security in jre directory.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like current JRE's ship both the limited and unlimited policy files under the JRE's install folder in `lib/security`, each in separate sub folders.  By default, in `lib/security/java.security`, the `limited` policy is used by default.  But if you uncomment the `crypto.policy=unlimited` line, that will allow Java to use the `unlimited` policy files and enable the 256-bit ciphers/algorithms.

Comment: This was true for (Oracle) 8u151/2 (Sep. 2017) only. 8u161/2 (Dec. 2017) up and all 9,10,11 have policy=unlimited out of the box.

Comment: Untrue for Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_80). `crypto.policy` does not exist in `lib/security/java.security` file.