# HttpsUrlConnection does not call createSocket of the set SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, android, sockets, ssl, httpurlconnection

I am currently working on an Android application in which one some https calls (I use a client certificate) are performed.

Here my code :

```
// We create the client PKCS12 certificate
final KeyStore clientCertificateKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
try
{
  clientCertificateKeyStore.load(this.clientCertificatePayload, this.clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray());
}
finally
{
  this.clientCertificatePayload.close();
}

final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(clientCertificateKeyStore, clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray());

final KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);

final URL url = new URL("https://myuri.com");
final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(getReadTimeout());
httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(getConnectTimeout());
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

final OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
final BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
bufferedWriter.write(body);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();

httpURLConnection.connect();
//...
```

This code works perfectly on my Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 but does not work on a Wiko Rainbow with Android 4.2.2. In fact, after setting the sslSocketFactory to my httpURLConnection, I have the following exception when I call the getOutputStream method :

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x631b60c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x59b4c8a8:0x00000000)
   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:421)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:450)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
   at com.splunk.mint.network.http.MonitorableHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(MonitorableHttpsURLConnection.java:93)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.performHttpRequest(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:472)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.performHttpRequest(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:562)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.getInputStream(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:158)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x631b60c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x59b4c8a8:0x00000000)
   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHand
```

I read on the Internet that I have to force the use of the TLS protocol and removed the SSLv3 protocols. For that, I found a lot of code samples including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037590/which-cipher-suites-to-enable-for-ssl-socket/23365536#23365536) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han).

So, I have updated my code like this :

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
  sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
  ((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
}
else
{
  sslSocketFactoryEx = new SSLSocketFactoryEx(keyManagers, null, null);
  ((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactoryEx);
}
```

But when I am in debug mode, the debugger never stops into the `createSocket` methods. I just have the impression that the `HttpsUrlConnection` does not use the factory I set to create the socket...

Did I miss a step in my implementation ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am aware it has been over three years, but did you find a workaround? Or just migrate to OkHttpclient?

Comment: @AgustinPazos : I have updated the minSDK to 21 since!