# MQQueueManager.<init> raises MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400' for specified MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

When creating MQQueueManager object with following sslCipherSuite:

```
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA";
MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
MQEnvironment.channel  = channel;
MQEnvironment.port = port;
iMQQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueMgr);
```

it manager init raises:

> MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'

which should means " JSSE reported that it does not support the CipherSuite specified by the application" (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q044280_.htm)

I've configured my Queue Manager -> Channels (Properties) -> SSL -> CipherSpec to: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (TLS 1.0, Secure Hash Algorithm, 128-bit AES encryption).

used platform is:

```
JAVA 7 (1.7.0_75-b13) 
MQ 7.1 client libs (7.1.0.6-k710-006-141112)
MQ 8.0 server (8.0.0.5)
```

here is the stack detail:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructMQCD(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1434)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructCNO(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1537)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:233)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:588)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:630)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:107)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:205)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:911)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:799)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:750)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:157)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:681)
```

I guess the issue is on MQ configuration side, due the fact that my jre

```
SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom())
.getSupportedSSLParameters()
.getCipherSuites()
```

returns "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" as one of CipherSuites. But I'm not sure what's exactly wrong on QMgr configuration. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Sorry using of TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite was not correct, even if the cipher is in getSupportedSSLParameters()
.getCipherSuites(), client raises [MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'] for anyelse nonsence string passed as sslCipherSuite.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the following 2 IBM MQ bulletins:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688165
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21688165

Comment: Thanks Roger, I didn't test connection from IBM SDK yet, but I'll have to do that as we deploy app on WebSphere, Weblogic and also stand alone JRE processes connects the MQ QManager.

Answer (score 0):

When I filter only MQ supported ciphers listed at [SSL/TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm)

and check all Java version : 1.7.0_75 supported ciphers filtered over MQ supported from link above I receive following result:

```
public class SSLSupported {

    // http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm
    static String[] MQ_SUPPORTED = { "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA",
            "SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA", 
            "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
            "SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256", 
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
            "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

        } };

        context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        SSLParameters params = context.getSupportedSSLParameters();
        String[] suites = params.getCipherSuites();
        System.out.println("Java version : " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
        System.out.println("Connecting with " + suites.length + " cipher suites supported:");

        List<String> mqSupported= Arrays.asList(MQ_SUPPORTED);

        for (int i = 0; i < suites.length; i++) 
            if (mqSupported.contains(suites[i])) 
                System.out.println(suites[i]);

    }

}

Java version : 1.7.0_75-b13
Connecting with 63 cipher suites supported:
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
```

I used following cipherSuite:

```
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

problem is that MQ QueueManager reported all these above as "Weak CipherSpec" e.g:

> (WARNING Weak CipherSpec) SSL 3.0, Secure Hash Algorithm, 168-bit Triple DES encryption

so I had to make configuration changes in MQ installation:
[mq.ini]

```
SSL:
AllowSSLV3=Y
AllowWeakCipherSpec=ALL
```

and also (as [Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431734/roger) noticed by [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39879052/1867646)):
[java.security]

```
#   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

than it starts to communicate over TLSv1, but I'd like to use TLSv1.2 ciphers and it still doesn't works, I used [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) (jre7) and also:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
```

or

```
MQEnvironment.sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactoryEx();
```

with SSLSocketFactoryEx implementation by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/1867646) post.

But nothing works well, so I'm still on TLSv1.