# Java regex for cipher suite hardening for TLS/SSL

Tags: java, regex, ssl, regex-lookarounds

I need Java Regex which can match the argument used to set ciphers for SSL/TLS

valid ciphers : 
(For testing multiple pattern at a go, added them to string with comma separated, later iterating each for pattern match)

```
"ALL:!kRSA:!CBC,ALL:-aRSA:-CBC:SHA256,ALL:!kRSA,ALL:!aRSA,ALL:!RSA,ALL:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA,ALL:!DES-CBC,ALL:!DES,ALL:-RSA+AES-128-CBC+SHA256";
```

Can be matched with regex = `"^((?:ALL)|(?:ALL)(:([!-]?(a|k)?[A-Z0-9]+([+-]?(a|k)?[A-Z0-9]+)?)*)*)$";`

But when I try invalid ciphers: (basically it should fail to match)

```
invalidciphers = "ALL:+DES,+DES,-DES,DEFAULT:-aRSA,akRSA,kDHE-aRSA,!ECDHE";
```

unable to create one.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Where would you find a comma-separated list like that??

Comment: @Andreas , sorry for that. As part of testing multiple ciphers i have added them to string. later iterating over it for individual pattern match .... Just for testing

Comment: It is really very unclear what your validation logic is. I think you doesn't really understand what those strings mean. E.g. why would both `ALL:!RSA` and `ALL:!DES` be ok, but `ALL:+DES` be bad? `ALL:!RSA` means that `DES` is ok, and `ALL:!DES` means that `RSA` is ok, so why wouldn't both `RSA` and `DES` be ok?

Comment: But you said that `ALL:!RSA` is valid, and that would allow `DES` ciphers. Alternative, you said that `ALL:!DES` is valid, and that would allow `RSA` ciphers. So you're saying the it's ok to allow `RSA` ciphers and it's ok to allow `DES` ciphers, as long as you don't allow both at the same time? That makes no sense.

Comment: Similarly, you say that `ALL:!aRSA` is ok, but `DEFAULT:-aRSA` is not? `DEFAULT` is stricter than `ALL`, so still not making much sense. Heck, why would you allow any of the `ALL` ciphers, given that `ALL` includes `SSLv2`? *Yikes!*

Comment: @Andreas there are certain rules for building cipher filter where in how to use !, +, -, :  and when to use. That's the reason why ALL:!DES is valid but ALL:+DES is not.

Comment: ! can be used before cipher,  + cannot be used like this ALL:+DSA:+ECDHE, - can be used like this ALL:-RSA:-DES, and when DEFAULT is used, no other character should follow

Comment: @Andreas , There are still more rules to be followed. And If followed, im unable to build one for pattern check.

Comment: Why can't you use `+`? It doesn't add anything, it just moves the cipher to the end. Do you understand the difference between `ALL:!RSA:RSA`, `ALL:!RSA:+RSA`, and `ALL:+RSA:-RSA`? All three result is *exactly the same* set of ciphers, i.e. the same as `ALL:!RSA`, and you said that's allowed.

Comment: @Andreas     + can only be used when combination of cipher suites to be mentioned like ALL:-RSA+AES-128-CBC+SHA256 , + should always be preceeded by cipher string      and       - is used in two ways 1. part of a cipher algorithm string or in combining a full cipher suite. 2. to remove the cipher suite containing that cipher

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133056/discussion-between-chetan-and-andreas).

Comment: So, you looking for this: `^(ALL)(:[!-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+([+-][ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*$`? See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Mp1OL1/1).

Comment: Cipher suite names are taken from IANA's [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4). The names are like `TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` and `TLS_RSA_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`. They will not match a cipher string like `HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4`. You retrieve the list of cipher suites from, say, `SSLSocketFactory` using `getDefaultCipherSuites` and `getEnabledCipherSuites`. Also see [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jww Please refer to OpenSSL cipher setting. The one you speak about with '_' are the actual cipher suites which are enabled/supported. Out of ALL supported cipher suites in TLS/SSL, if we need to filter out few and allow only specific cipher suites, we use CipherFilter (This is a Regex that I am working on)

Comment: @Andreas add your reply as answer, I will accept it. Just before that pls check this

1. ^(ALL)(:[!-]?[ake]?[A-Z0-9]+([+-][ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*$  works if String starts with ALL, 

2. ^([!]?[ake]?[A-Z0-9]+([+-]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)(:[!-]?[ake]?[A-Z0-9]+([+-][ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*$ works for all . But how not to allow ALL and DEFAULT in this?

3. ^DEFAULT$ only for DEFAULT

4. And can we merge these 3 regex to single regex

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/CEwDK0/1 will work. Not sure what the rules for combining these 3 are.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^ALL(?::[!-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+(?:[+-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*(?:,ALL(?::[!-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+(?:[+-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WAbAW4/2)

The scheme is `^<single_pattern>(?:,<single_pattern>)*$`. It matches the start of string, then the single pattern, and then 0 or more occurrences of a comma followed with the single pattern up to the end of string.

The `single_pattern` here is `ALL(?::[!-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+(?:[+-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*`:

- `ALL` - a substring
- `(?::[!-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+(?:[+-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `[!-]?` - an optional `!` or `-`
  - `[ak]?` - an optional `a` or `k`
  - `[A-Z0-9]+` - 1+ uppercase letters or digits
  - `(?:[+-]?[ak]?[A-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

    - `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
    - `[ak]?` - an optional `a` or `k`
    - `[A-Z0-9]+` - 1+ uppercase letters or digits